# NativeControls plugin doesn't work with Cordova 2.7.0

Tags: iphone, cordova

`Cordova 2.7.0` no longer allows deprecated forms of calls to `cordova.exec`. For example:
 44.  `2013-05-09 01:18:29.850 myiOSApp[9764:17903]` The old format of this exec call has been removed 1
deprecated since 2.1). Change to:`cordova.exec(null, null, "NativeControls", createTabBar",[]);`

The latest version of the iOS NativeControls plugin I know of is at [Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) and it has not been updated to fix this.

Is there a more recent version of NativeControls anywhere else?

Please help me to fix this issues

by

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a changes in 2.1 deprecated previous iOS plugin signature to: (void)myMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

I've fork the project and made fixes here:  https://github.com/noogen/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/NativeControls

Comment: Thanks for your help Noogen. but how to i add tabbar item ?

Comment: I just apply a fix, no change were made to the API.  So the code work the same as sample here in main.js: https://gist.github.com/nathanpc/1384250

Comment: Thanks a lot Noogen. I fixed Native control tabbar issues

Comment: Please vote for this answer.  Also, did you have to do anything else in addition to my fix?  I'm interested to know if it's working so I can submit a pull request to merge the fix back into github master.

Comment: Hey Noogen, Is there support for phonegap 2.7.0? I am having trouble importing the plugin .h and .m into xcode. T

Comment: My apologise, I was not using the most recent git. Will se if it all works fine :)